# ABRT processes in Linux - What are they and how do I terminate them

Tags: linux

I have a Linux x86_64 VM running on a Cloud server and I had rebooted it once using the abort option.
After that , I am getting the `abrt-server` processes when I run `ps -ef` command

```
root      4857  1251  0 14:56 ?        00:00:00 abrt-server -s
root      4993  1251  0 14:56 ?        00:00:00 abrt-server -s
root      5087  1251  0 14:57 ?        00:00:00 abrt-server -s
root      5223  1251  0 14:57 ?        00:00:00 abrt-server -s
root      5382  1251  0 14:58 ?        00:00:00 abrt-server -s
root      5565  1251  0 14:58 ?        00:00:00 abrt-server -s
root      7388  1251  0 14:59 ?        00:00:00 abrt-server -s
root      7609  1251  0 14:59 ?        00:00:00 abrt-server -s
```

What are these ABRT processes and how do I terminate them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ABRT stands for the
[Automatic Bug Reporting Tool](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/deployment_guide/ch-abrt).

From this Red Hat solution article: [What would be the impact of disabling the ABRT service?](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/656643) :

> - What is the impact of disabling the ABRT service ?
>
> The user would not
> be reported of any crashes happening on the system and would need to
> monitor the system and `/var/log/messages` constantly for any crashes
> happening. User should consider disabling the service only if `ABRT`
> service is of low importance in your environment and have an alternate
> problem detecting tool monitoring the system.

To stop it until the next reboot:

```
systemctl stop abrtd
```

To disable it for the future:

```
systemctl disable abrtd
```